# odd media mount issue possibly after windows update on dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

Since yesterday I have an odd behaviour in linux on my dualboot system that I find hard to explain but i will give it a try, first my system setup how it used to be, then what it changed into. As far as I know this happened after I had to boot into the windows and had an extensive windows update. I am not aware of anything else that changed since then.

Previously thouth to be the "Previous setup":

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1  54 GB Fat                               = mounted @ /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p2 106 GB Ext4                              = mounted @ Filesystem Root
/dev/nvme0n1p3 736 GB NTFS "Files"                      = Mounted @ /media/matter/**Files**  
/dev/nvme0n1p4 103 GB NTFS "Windows"                    = unmounted / accessable but as drive not as media folder. 
**/dev/nvme0n1p5 ???**
**/dev/nvme0n1p6 ???**
```

current setup: 1TB SSD

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1  54 GB Fat                               = mounted @ /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p2 106 GB Ext4                              = mounted @ Filesystem Root
/dev/nvme0n1p3 736 GB NTFS "Files"                      = Mounted @ **/media/matter/Files1**  
/dev/nvme0n1p4 103 GB NTFS "Windows"                    = Mounted @ **/media/matter/Files**
/dev/nvme0n1p5 659 MB NTFS             windows recovery = not mounted
/dev/nvme0n1p6 1.1 GB NTFS "Dell Supp" windows recovery = not mounted
```

my etc/fstab is as follows which i believe to be unchanged:

```
PARTUUID=e294be36-f7d0-430c-a5b3-e5067ea39832 /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 0
UUID=6f3c28a9-64af-497d-a0db-9797ea2cae93 / ext4 noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/sda1 /media/Music ntfs defaults 0 1
/dev/nvme0n1p4 /media/matter/Files ntfs defaults 0 1
```

because of the change from my files partition to mount **/media/matter/Files1**, my remaps in home/.config/user-dir.dirs got changed back to $HOME/, and does that again after every reboot.

I feel the issue is that I have to stop the windows partition to be mounted at all on startup, especially as /media/matter/Files. Unfortunately I don't know where to start. Should i solve this in windows (in windows things don't seem to have changed) or in ubuntu and if so, of course how.

any thoughts will be very much appreciated.

Kind regards

Matthieu

Answer (score 1):

### Topical Solution

(Use on cuts, bruises, burns, wounds, but not blue screens; they bite back)

---

Add an entry in `/etc/fstab` that prevents auto-mounting of the concerned partition.

1. Get the `UUID` for the problematic partition

   ```
   $ lsblk -no UUID /dev/nvme0n1p4
   <long-hex-uuid-thingy-thing>
   ```
2. Add the following line to your `/etc/fstab`

   ```
   # <comment-that-reminds-you-of-the-pain-you-went-through>
   UUID=<long-hex-uuid-thingy-thing>   none   ntfs   defaults,noauto   0 0
   ```

   (you can replace `none` above with a default mount point of choice. In fact, `none` is technically incorrect here, but works fine because of the `noauto` flag — until you try a guess-mount like `sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p4`...)
3. Peace should then be restored in the universe

### Surgery

---

First off, when you say “*media folder*,” I think you misunderstand what linux means by that; `/media/<user-name>` is the default mount location for drives mounted by `<user-name>` — i.e., somebody who isn’t the superuser, or an elevated daemon.

So by default, if said partition was not mounted *at all* on boot (or by any other elevated daemon) — not even R/O, one would **expect** it to get mounted in `/media/<user-name>` when one clicks on it in Nautilus (the file manager).

To the fact that your Windows system-partition wouldn’t auto-mount before this update, my best guess is that the update changed the GPT attributes of the partition. There is one (the 63rd bit or `0x8000000000000000`) that [Microsoft implements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/gpt#parameters) as a 'do not auto-mount' flag (which is what `gdisk` refers to it as too).

As for why the volume is being mounted as "Files" instead of "Windows"... that stumps me :/

Comment: thank you so much for your elaborate, clear and humorous answer! much appreciated!! unfortunately i have to leave now but i will definitely implement it tomorrow or over the weekend and come back too you with my results. kind regards Matthieu

Comment: No problem! 
Quite intrigued about the weird mount-point naming though…

Comment: implementing your answer opened my eyes to the cause of the issue, which i added as answer. never the less i would've never found that without your answer. so many thanks. still there are some ?? to me which i added as end of my "answer", maybe you understand that?

Comment: Hi @MatthieuKintsvan! I’m commenting here since I’ve recently started out on Stack-*, so I don’t have enough reputation to comment on your answer xD. 2.) Actually, I don’t think the “Files” partition (`nvme0n1p3`) even _gets_ auto-mounted at boot. Here it’s just a case of when you click on it in Nautilus/`gnome-disks`; it gets mounted by _you_ (not root). It shows up as _Files1_ because by then there’s already a folder named `Files` there.

Comment: As for question 1, Windows is mysterious sometimes xD. My best guess is that there was previously an [**MSR**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition#Purpose) partition there (the [default setup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#microsoft-reserved-partition-msr)) just before the files partition.

Answer (score 0):

Due to MarbleMuffins clear answer my eyes were opened to something i should've seen earlier.

```
/dev/nvme0n1p4 /media/matter/Files ntfs defaults 0 1
```

used to refer to the "Files" partition, which is now nvme0n1p3 instead of nvme0n1p4 and the windows partition is now nvme0n1p4 (former name is unknown). So the formerly right line in etc/fstab now mounts the wrong partition under the wrong name.

clear to me now is that the "former" setup is what i thought it to be, has indeed been incorrect.

what still confuses me is:

1. why did the windows update make a change in the partitions
2. why did the nvme0n1p3 "files" partition still get mounted (as this is why i once added the line to fstab, which now refers to windows) and now as Files1.